# Why does System.out.println() in Java print to the console?

Tags: java

I read several posts online explaining what `System.out.println()` is in Java. Most of them go like this:

> - [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a `final` class in the `java.lang` package.
> - [`out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a `public static` object inside the `System` class of type [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).
> - [`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) prints a line of text to the output stream.

My question is when we do `System.out.println()` in our code, why does it end up writing to the console? [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/redirecting-system-out-println-output-to-a-file-in-java/) explains how we can make it write to a file by calling `System.setOut()`. So my question translates to where is `System.setOut()` called to redirect its output to the console?

I checked `System.setOut()`'s [source](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L169). It makes a call to `setOut0()` which is a `native` method. This method is [directly called](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L1141) inside the `initializeSystemClass()` method by passing it `fdOut` which is a `FileOutputStream` defined [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#L1138). I did not find a console output stream passed to `setOut0()` anywhere, nor did I find a call to the non-native `setOut()` done anywhere. Is it done somewhere else outside the `System` class by the JVM while starting execution? If so, can someone point me to it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the console, it is the standard output stream of the process. That is normally the console but may well be a file or something else. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams.

Comment: is it defined anywhere in code?

Comment: The `fdout` actually output to console. I suppose it is `FileOutputStream` as in Linux/Unix system, io device is also treated as file.

Comment: Are you asking "When java starts up, how is the `out` initially set?" and "From where is it set?" This is how I read your Question, but it seems to me that answers are answering something else.

Comment: I haven't checked that part of the Java sources, but I would assume it comes from the standard C libraries, i.e. the native libraries that the JVM code links to, which in turn get it from the operating system.

Comment: Does this help? [How System.out.println() really works](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/)

Comment: This is probably done by the JVM at startup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My doubt is when we do `System.out.println()` in our code, why it ends up in writing to console?

In any POSIX compliant shell, each process gets three "standard" streams when the shell starts it:

- The "standard input" stream is for reading input.
- The "standard output" stream is for writing ordinary output.
- The "standard error" stream is for writing error output.

(The same idea is also used in many non-POSIX compliant shells as well.)

For an *interactive* POSIX shell, the default is for these streams to read from and write to the shell's "console" ... which could be a physical console, but is more likely to be a "terminal emulator" on the user's (ultimate) desktop machine.  (Details vary.)

A POSIX shell allows you to redirect the standard streams in various ways; e.g.

```
$ some-command < file     # read stdin from 'file'
$ some-command > file     # write stdout to 'file'
$ some-command 2> file    # write stderr to 'file'
$ some-command << EOF     # read stdin from a 'here' document
  lines of input
  ...
  EOF
$ some-command | another  # connect stdout for one command to
                          # stdin for the next one in a pipeline
```

and so on.  If you do this, one or more of the standard streams is NOT connected to the console.

Further reading:

- ["What are stdin, stdout and stderr on Linux?"](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/)
- ["Standard Streams"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

---

So how does this relate to the question?

When a Java program start, the `System.in/out/err` streams are connected to the standard input / output / error streams specified by the parent process; typically a shell.

In the case of `System.out`, that *could* be the console (however you define that) or it *could* be a file, or another program or ... `/dev/null`.  But where the output goes is determined by how the JVM was launched.

So, the literal answer is "because that is what the parent process has told the Java program to do".

---

> How internally shell communicates with jvm to set standard input / output in both Windows and Linux?

This is what happens with Linux, UNIX, Mac OSX and similar.  (I don't know for Windows ... but I imagine it is similar.)

Suppose that the shell is going to run `aaa > bbb.txt`.

1. The parent shell forks a child process ... sharing the parent shell's address space.
2. The child process closes file descriptor 1 (the standard output file descriptor)
3. The child process opens "bbb.txt" for writing on file descriptor 1.
4. The child process execs the "aaa" command, and it becomes the "aaa" command process.  The file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are preserved by the exec call.
5. The "aaa" command starts ...

When the "aaa" command starts, it finds that file descriptors 0 and 2 (stdin and stderr) refer to the same "file" as the parent shell.  File descriptor 1 (stdout) refers to "bbb.txt".

The same thing happens when "aaa" is the `java` command.

Comment: I tried doing `java MyJava abcd`. `sysout` in my java code printed "Hello abcd!!!" on console. When I did `java MyJava abcd > textfile.txt`, `sysout` in my java code output "Hello abcd!!!" to textfile.txt. So I got that now. Now am trying to understand: "because that is what the parent process has told the Java program to do". Specifically what exactly "technically" happens when we specify `>` vs when we dont specify it? That is, how internally shell communicates with jvm to set standard input / output in both Windows and Linux?

Comment: @mercury - What are you trying to achieve?  You don't need to import anything to use `System.out`.  What does this have to do with this Question + Answer?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to. We can redirect to somewhere else. Here is the code to re-direct into the file:

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
System.setOut(output);
System.out.println("This will be written to file");
```

By default, the console is the standard output stream (System.in) in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` does not print to the console, it prints to the *standard output stream* (`System.out` is Java's name of the standard output stream). The standard output stream is usually the console, but it doesn't have to be. The Java runtime just wraps the standard output stream of the operating system in a nice Java object.

A non-interactive program often uses a few standard input and output channels: it reads input from the standard input stream, does some operations on it, and produces output on the standard output stream. The standard output stream can be the console, but it can also be piped to the standard input stream of another program or to a file. In the end, the operating system running the programming decides what the standard output stream output to.

For example, in Unix terminals you can do something like:

```
java -jar your.program.jar > output.txt
```

and store the output of your program in a text file, or

```
java -jar your.program.jar | grep hello
```

to only display the lines of the output which contain 'hello'. Only if you don't specify another destination, the standard output stream writes to the console.